# Function that will act like an Strlen C++

Tags: c++, strlen

I want to make a function that will do the same as Strlen does, andI get the error: "string subscript out of range". I tried fixing it but has no idea.

heres the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int strlen1( string str)
{
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    while (str[i]!='\0')
        {
            count++;
            i++;
    }
    return count;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << strlen1(input) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: c++ strings can be, but do not have to be null terminated.

Comment: why `count++; i++;`? You only need one... but that's not the problem...

Comment: Have you seen the std::string documentation? http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

Comment: `int i; for(i=0; i<str.size(); ++i) { } return i;`

Comment: @PigBen: str = string(42, '\0');

Comment: @PigBen: That doesn't compile. You need: `int i ; for (i=0; i<str.size(); ++i) { } return i;` HTH

Comment: @TonyK: My code is never right the first time.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels, I wouldn't know where to start telling you. __Get a book!__ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, for a non-`const` `std::string`accessing an element beyond the string length has Undefined Behavior (more precisely, when using the non-`const` `operator[]` for that).

C++98 **§21.3.4/1**, about `std::string::operator[]`:

> If `pos < size`, returns `data()[pos]`. Otherwise, if `pos == size()`, the `const` version returns `charT()`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

And your string is non-`const`.

You can make it `const`, which will then invoke a special provision in the standard that guarantees zero result for element *n*, but that does not address the problem that your function is completely redundant for `std::string`.

Perhaps you mean to have argument type `char const*`.

That would make more sense, and then also the function would work.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: the const made it work, but as you said i think that the right solution is to have argument type char* instead of string. unfortunately, when i replaced it in str and input variables it didnt work saying the variable 'input' is being used without being intialized. i have no idea how to make it work

Comment: Just change the `str` variable to a `const char *`; leave `input` as a `string`.  Then call it like `strlen1(input.c_str())`.

Comment: Never knew it. Apparently in C++0x `s[s.size()]` will always return a reference to a NUL character (and you must not modify the value).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the misconception that std::string is the same as a C-style string (char const*).  This is simply not true.  There is no null terminator.

Here's your strlen function the only way it will work:

```
int strlen1(string str) { return static_cast<int>(str.size()); }
```

Comment: Actually there is effectively a null-terminator, as soon as you make the string `const`.

Comment: Not sure why you'd say constness matters here.  Null is not considered a terminator for std::string.

Comment: I did.  It's right in that Null is returned, but you are in error here when you call it a terminator.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: const matters because strlen1 should proudly announce to the world it won't destroy the string to get it's size... as does size() method prototype `size_t size() const;`

Comment: @kriss - sure, but it doesn't magically make 0 a terminator in std::string.

Comment: @Noah: "in error when you call it a terminator", <-- technobabble.

Comment: Calling it that doesn't make your statements accurate.

Comment: @Noah: what's wrong? why can't you take a simple technical correction?

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a nice `size()` method for this.

Comment: are you sure you have to create a strlenb function that takes a std::string as an argument, not a `char*` ?

Comment: you right, i've made mistake, need it as char*. unfortunately, when i replaced it in str and input variables it didnt work saying the variable 'input' is being used without being intialized. i have no idea how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

strlen is based on zero terminated strings (char*, or char arrays), [C++ string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) are based on length + data, you can't access to data after the end of string (where a terminal zero would be). Beside that, getting the length is a standard property of C++ strings (size()), hence the standard way of writing strlen is just to call size.

Comment: Actually, for a *constant* `std::string` of length *n*, accessing element *n* (which is beyond the string length) is required to yield `'\0'`. It's a special case provision in the standard. So if the OP had just added a little `const` to the formal argument type the `strlen1` function would have been technically OK.

Comment: what do you mean sero teminated strings? and how do you think i can create a strlen function by my own?

Comment: @Aviran: I mean creating a strlen function based on std::string as input is probably one of dumber thing I ever heard of. If it's some homework you should consider looking for a better teacher.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: technically ok, you say it, and there is many ways to do the same thing that would work without const. But I agree for a function like strlen, making parameter const looks logical, I wouldn't like a strlen that is allowed to destroyed the original string to compute the length.